# Access a variable with a string version of the variable name - vb.net

Tags: vb.net

In VB.net, I handle many button clicks in one method. Then I use a select case to figure out what to do with the request, see below:

```
Private Sub picT1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles picT2.Click, picT3.Click, picT4.Click,

        Select Case sender.name
            Case "picT2"
                If PLC.T2Shutter = BitOff Then do something...
            Case "picT3"
                If PLC.T3Shutter = BitOff Then do something...
            Case "picT4"
                If PLC.T4Shutter = BitOff Then do something...
        End Select

End Sub
```

Since I am going to manipulate a variable with similar indexing (PLC.T2Shutter from picT2.Click event), how can I address the right variable by somehow using the received "2" in the name of the sender?

Comment: see my answer below. If you didn't vote please do do and accept if that was the answer or ask for clarification

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to have `PLC.Shutter(shutterNumber)` instead of individually named properties for each one. Or `PLC.T.Shutter()`, etc.